# Why doesn't the website default to index.html by default?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, .net-core, elm

I'm unable to put in the domain name to observe the landing page:

```
http://some_url.com
```

**Error:**

> Could not find file 'E:\index.html'.

However, the following works:

> http://some_url.com/index.html

FYI:
This website was built with Elm, Giraffe, and .Net Core.

Comment: Why down-vote? I'm not a web developer and thus provided details on how I can view the website and what tools were used.

Comment: That's how it was configured, for whatever reason...

Comment: Windows? Linux? IIS or not? There are far too many reasons this kind of issue can happen, so when you post a question, don't hide anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running Giraffe, then you're running F# which means there's a good chance you're using `IApplicationBuilder` for configuring your server. You should be able to call `UseDefaultFiles`, then `UseStaticFiles` to use index.html as a default document.

```
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler
    app.UseDefaultFiles() |> ignore
    app.UseStaticFiles() |> ignore
    app.UseGiraffe webApp
```

From [Serving Static Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-a-default-document):

> `UseDefaultFiles` must be called before `UseStaticFiles` to serve the default file. `UseDefaultFiles` is a URL re-writer that doesn't actually serve the file. You must enable the static file middleware (`UseStaticFiles`) to serve the file.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't specify the following:

```
let webApp: HttpHandler = 
    choose [
        GET >=>
            choose [
                route "/" >=> htmlFile "index.html"
```

Comment: While this method works for the root `/` URL, it does not carry over to default documents in other directories (e.g. `/foo` will still 404 even if you do have a `/foo/index.html`). The `app.UseDefaultFiles()` approach applies the logic to all folders on the website.

Comment: Hey Scott, it looks like Chad's answer above is correct from what I can tell. If this is the case then please consider accepting it as the answer.